# Problem In Separating The Interface And The Implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Its the first time I am trying to separate the class in a separate header file but I am getting an error.Please help me out.Thanks
**CODE:**

My main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <MyClass>
int MyClass::data;
int main()
{
    cout<<"data="<<MyClass::data;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
#ifndef MyClass
#define <MyClass>
class MyClass
{
    static int data_;
    
};
#endif
```

**Error:** fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MyClass.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Your question is a bit too long; please shrink it before you get too many answers.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What do you mean this question "is a bit too long"? Finally someone included source code *and* compiler errors. I'm getting tired of posting comments asking for them, and you're requesting that people *shorten* their questions?

Comment: @Cody: Did you see the *unedited* version of the question?

Comment: @Mehrdad:I think that the unedited version was also fine.It just did not had the line I have added before my code.I thought that my title and the heading states all.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes; I approved the edit. It had about 5 extra lines. Obviously they just copied and pasted the contents of the Output Window. From my vantage point, that's far superior to the alternative. I'm used to parsing the contents of the Output Window. I can simply ignore extra information; I can't infer what error messages say when they aren't there.

Comment: @Cody: I was referring to the very original version, and suffice it to say that it wasn't as well-written as it is now. Feel free to ignore my comment above, since it no longer applies. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

angle brackets are for system headers.

Also it's `data` or `data_`?

Also it would be better something like

```
#if !defined(MYCLASS_H_INCLUDED)
#define MYCLASS_H_INCLUDED

...

#endif
```

`#define`-ing a name identical to the class name is going to be a source of problems

Answer (score 2):

First good idea to separate definition and implementation in C++. Your `#include` directive shall use `"` and not `<` `>` as your header is not a system header. Or your header is not lying inside the same directory than the cpp file.

That is another topic but OO is more than just using some classes. Encapsulating static variables inside a class doesn't make them less global... At least they have another namespace...

Answer (score 0):

use #include "Myclass.h" instead of #include